# how to receive a json response

Tags: java, android, json, http

I need the response to be converted to a string..

```
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();  
        Log.d("HTTP","Exe");
        String url=Sign(token);
        Log.d("HTTP","Exe");

        HttpPost httpPost;
        httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
```

The response(json) is supposed to be something like

```
{
    "url": "http://db.tt/APqhX1",
    "expires": "Tue, 01 Jan 2030 00:00:00 +0000"
}
```

how do i receive it?I am working on Android(java)..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is the way to get any json as a http response. I hope it would be usefull.

```
HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
InputStream is = entity.getContent();

try {
     BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "utf-8"), 256);
 StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
 String line = null;
 while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)  sb.append(line); 
     result = sb.toString();
 is.close();
} catch (Exception e) {}

 JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);
 for(int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {
JSONObject json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
String url= json_data.getString("url");
    String expires= json_data.getString("expires");
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many examples if you google and try out anyways:

```
      response = client.execute(httpPost);
  HttpEntity httpEntity = response.getEntity();
  InputStream is = httpEntity.getContent();
```

.. convert Inputstream to string